# Turn a H3 tag into a link via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I turn the following h3 tag into a clickable link (and set it href) via jQuery, while keeping the H3 mark and adding an  tag.
My current code for example:
    Click Here

Comment: [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [wrap function](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) that makes this easy:

```
(function($){
    var $hTag = $('.makemealink');

    $hTag.wrap('<a href="#"></a>');
})(jQuery);
```

This will wrap the h3 like:

```
<a href="#">
    <h3 class="makemealink">Click Here</h3>
</a>
```

Comment: Will that retain the <h3> tag?

Comment: No, if you want to keep the h3 tag, then use wrap, updated answer!

Comment: @Sam Or, if you want the `<a>` inside the `<h3>`, use `.wrapInner` instead of `.wrap` -- would make `<h3 class="makemealink"><a href="#">Click Here</a></h3>`